# Make popup on all window

Tags: .net, wpf, xaml, popup

Is it possible to make `popup` on all window?

Previously I had `Grid` with `ZIndex = 1000` (size of `grid` was like all page/screen) which was displayed over others elements. But when I've added `popup` to page which also should be under that `grid`, but it wasn't, I thought about make `Popup` from that `Grid`.

```
<Popup IsOpen="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type UserControl}}, Path=IsLoading, Mode=OneWay}" AllowsTransparency="True" Placement="Absolute" PopupAnimation="Fade" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Focusable="False">
    <Grid Panel.ZIndex="1000" Background="#A5000000" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
      Visibility="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type UserControl}}, Path=IsLoading, Mode=OneWay, Converter={StaticResource BoolToVis}}">
        </Grid>
        ...
    </Grid>
</Popup>
```

This is what I have now. This popup is like "limited" rectangle in top left corner (limited in size).

Answer (score 0):

Set Height and width for popup using this.

```
Height="{Binding ActualHeight,ElementName=RootGrid}"
Width="{Binding ActualWidth,ElementName=RootGrid}"
```

Comment: well, yes. I've tried it, but it doesn't help. Maybe I am wrong but I heard somewhere that Popup can cover max 75% of screen... So with Actual-values I have bottom part of screen uncovered by popup

Comment: Set HorizontalAlignment and VerticalAlignment to center

Comment: `Alignment` also doesn't help. Still all page isn't covered with popup